# Explanation and usage of -d option in java

Tags: java, javac

How does -d works in java please anybody can give the explanation of this.

Comment: jsut sets the destination directory for class files

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: type `java -h` to read the help file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options):

```
-d directory
```

> Sets the destination directory for class files. If a class is part of
>   a package, then javac puts the class file in a subdirectory that
>   reflects the package name and creates directories as needed.

For example:

***Oracle Solaris, Linux, and OS X***: If you specify

```
-d /home/myclasses and the class is called com.mypackage.MyClass
```

then the class file is /home/myclasses/com/mypackage/MyClass.class.

***Windows***: If you specify

```
-d C:\myclasses and the class is called com.mypackage.MyClass
```

then the class file is C:\myclasses\com\mypackage\MyClass.class.

*If the -d option isn’t specified, then javac puts each class file in the same directory as the source file from which it was generated.*